# WCF REST help page conflicts with UriTemplate

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a root UriTemplate that returns default data when no parameters are specified.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
```

and I have seen that approach used in several examples.

However, I added another template accepting a simple path variable:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{code}")]
```

which would then filter the default list by a code.

So for example *http://localhost/items* (as the base ServiceRoute) displays the default list of items, and *http://localhost/items/ABC* displays item 'ABC'.

The problem is that now *http://localhost/items/help* now displays a 404 error instead of the auto-generated help page, since it sees 'help' as a value for the 'code' parameter (and the operation returns a "Not Found" status when no records are matched).

Any ideas on how to keep that UriTemplate but not lose the help page?

Comment: The problem was the wrong configuration elements in my web.config, as obvious as that seems now, but I wasn't seeing it. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the help page stopped working is because the `helpEnabled` property defined as a `standardEndpoint` under `webHttpEndpoint` was somehow replaced with a wcf 'soap' metadata enabling configuration.

So the correct web.config section for enabling the help page in REST .Net 4.0 is, as is well documented:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Even though I started with Microsoft/Tony Sneed templates to create the REST project, which configured this properly, what I think happened is that I also added an OData service to the web application. Whether or not that is the reason, the above configuration got replaced with:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Now if you stare at that long enough and google 'help page wcf rest' at 1am, this is of course how wsdl 'help' is enabled for wcf 'soap-style' services and so you see the matching syntax and think that help is correctly enabled for REST and so you blame the issue on the UriTemplates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your .svc address.

So instead of doing it like:

```
http://localhost/items/help
```

Do it like

```
http://localhost/items.svc/help
```

It is in the comments from here:
[MSDN Rest Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx)

Comment: It is .Net 4 and uses a RouteTable to eliminate the .svc extension:    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("items", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyItemsService)));